# Save query to spreadsheet on local machine

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

Does anyone have a code snippet to handle the following? (Coldfusion and/or Javascript):

1. Press button to initiate saving a query as an Excel spreadsheet
2. Create the file and present the user a dialog to save the file locally (i.e. on the client device, not the server).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: cfspreadsheet, cfheader, and cfcontent are the coldfusion tags you need, assuming you have the query part sorted out.

Comment: Many thanks, Dan. How do I tie the three together? When I use <cfheader> and <cfcontent> I get a dialog which wants to open the original CF file, not the spreadsheet. I have:  <cfheader name="test" value="inline; filename=temp.xlsx">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel">. Tks!

Comment: If you don't want the file actually saved on the server, but streamed to the browser, look at the [Spreadsheet Functions](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Spreadsheet+functions).  You will still need cfheader and cfcontent tags to stream it to the browser

Comment: Many thanks. That's very helpful. Any tips on how to stream it such that the destination is selected by the user in a dialog? Tks!

Comment: This question is off topic because it is a 'icanhazcodez' question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closer than you think.   The last time I did this, the circumstances were a bit different than what you describe.  The file had been written and the user had to submit another form to download it.  The code I use is:

```
<cfheader
name="content-disposition" 
value="Attachment;#GetFileFromPath(form.ExportFilepath)#">

<cfcontent  file="#form.ExportFilePath#" 
type="application/vnd.ms-excel">
```

The time before that was a bit more traditional.  The user submitted a form to a page that did a bunch of stuff concluding with:

```
<cfset SpreadSheetSetActiveSheetNumber(Workbook, 1)>

<cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="#FileName#" name="Workbook"  
sheet=1 sheetname="Search Parameters" overwrite=true>

<cfheader name="content-disposition"   value="Attachment;filename=#Filename#">

<cfcontent file="#Filename#" type="application/vnd.ms-excel">
```

Workbook was created with a SpreadsheetNew() function.

Comment: Many thanks! That looks good, and I'll play around with that . . .